# Как сделать рандомный пример?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Можно ли сделать функцию для генерации примеров по типу `'1+7'` или `'4+6'` и чтобы можно было выбрать сложность.

Например:

- 1 - тогда только + и -
- 2 уже  умножение
- 3 деление
- 4 уже %

Как  сделать саму структуру понимаю,но что сделать с Math не знаю :)
(если можно сделать что-то подобное регуляркой,буду рад)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function generate_example(lvl) {
  // Дополнительная функция, чтобы генерировать случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 10
  function rn() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  }
  
  const operator = {
    1: Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-',
    2: '*',
    3: '/',
    4: '%'
  };
  return `${rn()} ${operator[lvl]} ${rn()}`;
}

console.log(generate_example(1));
console.log(generate_example(1));
console.log(generate_example(2));
console.log(generate_example(3));
console.log(generate_example(4));
```

Comment: А можно ли генерировать число от 0 до 100 ?

Comment: @KristalkillPlay, поправил. Чтобы получить лимит случайного числа, просто умножайте случайное число от `Math.random()` на 10, 100 или больше, если нужно. Пример: получим `0.231213 * 10`, получим  `2.31212`, и потом закругляем в меньшую сторону.